# How to change page title on hyperlink click from code behind (.aspx.cs) in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My button is inside Update Panel
I tried setting the title of page inside Page_Load :-
this.Title = "Projects";

and tried inside link click which is inside gridview which is in update panel-
`protected void lnkProjectName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {this.Title = "Project Phase";}`

Everytime it's displying the title as 'Projects' only and after clicking on the link button not updating
Thank you in advance

Comment: Create a [MCVE]. You haven't shown how you wired up your link button, haven't shown the UpdatePanel that it's inside, your Page_Load method doesn't look like actual code etc.

Comment: probably is not change the title, its only change what is inside the update panel - find some other way to do that update